# How to productionise Python script for AWS Glue?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue, production

I'm following this tutorial video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EzQArFt_On4

The example code provided in this video:

```
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.context import SparkContext

glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())
glueJob = Job(glueContext)
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

glueJob.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

sparkSession = glueContext.spark_session

#ETL process code
def etl_process():
  ...
  return xxx

glueJob.commit()
```

I'm wondering if the part before the function `etl_process` can be used in production directly? Or do I need to wrap that part into a separate function so that I can add unit test for it?
something like this:

```
def define_spark_session():
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
    glue_context = GlueContext(sc)
    glue_job = Job(glue_context)

    args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

    glue_job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

    spark_session = glue_context.spark_session
    return spark_session
```

But it seems doesn't need a parameter...

Or should I just write unit test for `etl_process` function?

Or maybe I can create a separate python file with `etl_process` function and import it in this script?

I'm new to this, a bit confused, might someone be able to help please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for now it is very difficult to test AWS Glue itself locally, although there are some solutions like downloading a docker image AWS provides you and run it from there (you'll probably need some tweaks but should be all right).

I guess the easies way is to transform the `DynamicFrame` you get from `gluelibs` into a Spark `DataFrame` (`.toDf()`) and then do thinks in pure Spark (PySpark) so you'll be able to test the result.

```
dataFrame = dynamic_frame.toDf()

def transormation(dataframe):
   return dataframe.withColumn(...)

def test_transformation()
   result = transformation(input_test_dataframe)
   assert ...
```